# Using mysql_affected_row to prevent race condition

Tags: mysql, myisam

Is it safe to use the following code to prevent race conditions? (`key` and `status` fields and mysql_affected_rows are used to implement locking)

```
$mres = mysql_query("SELECT `values`, `key`, `status` 
                     FROM `test`
                     WHERE `id` = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($mres);
if($row['status'] != UPDATING) {
    $mres = mysql_query("UPDATE `test` SET
                             `status` = UPDATING,
                             `key` = `key` + 1
                         WHERE `id` = 1 AND `key` = ".$row['key']);
    if($mres && mysql_affected_rows()) {
        //update here safely and then...
        mysql_query("UPDATE `test` SET
                        `status` = NOT_UPDATING,
                        `key` = `key` + 1
                     WHERE `id` = 1");
    }
}
```

My test shows that either it is not safe or I should search for a well-hidden mistake in my code.
Table is MyISAM

Comment: It seems to be correct, the only error might be if `id` is not the PRIMARY/UNIQUE key in your table. Also, you need to put `UPDATING` as a string in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should "acquire the lock" first before you retrieve values. Otherwise they may change before you get the lock.

```
$mres = mysql_query("UPDATE `test` SET
                             `status` = 'UPDATING'
                         WHERE `id` = 1 AND `status` = 'NOT_UPDATING'");
if ($mres && mysql_affected_rows()) {
    // got the lock
    // now select and update
}
```

- `id` better be a unique field in the db or things may behave very weird
- I couldn't see a reason to increment key
- notice I quoted the strings `'UPDATING'` and `'NOT_UPDATING'` in sql
- in your code, you should have also checked that `$row['status']` had a meaningful value(what if it was false/null?) before comparing to the php constant `UPDATING`
- hopefully you understand enough php to know that php strings *should* be quoted.

Comment: Maybe UPDATING and NOT_UPDATING are constants?

Comment: ya I was debating about that... I really doubt it though. The code smells of someone who had the misfortune of learning php/mysql from one of the billion crappy php/mysql blog tutorials polluting the internet.

Comment: Yeah, but I still like the question. However is this really a good way to prevent race condition? Why not to use `GET_LOCK()`?

Comment: that looks better, I didn't know GET_LOCK existed.

Comment: I also wonder what will happen if you use mysql_affected_rows() inside transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `GET_LOCK` and `RELEASE_LOCK` functions in MySql to simulate row locks.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock

With this approach you don't need to update rows. Also with `mysql_affected_rows()` if something goes wrong you may finish with always locked row (for example if you script crash before releasing row by updating it status to NOT_UPDATING). Locks granted with `GET_LOCK` are released automatically when connection is terminated.